# C# GridView doesn't show SQL Procedure returns

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, sql-server-2012

My procedure returns 25 rows. And I saw it in `DataContext` when running in debug mode. But after databound gridview doesn't show anything. When I change the `select` clause to

```
Select * 
from pgnchess 
order by GameID 
OFFSET @Offset ROW 
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROW ONLY
```

everything is ok. When I execute procedure in SQL Server Management Studio without any parameters also running very well.

Here is my SQL Server procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGamesWithPlayer](
    @qText nvarchar(40) = '%',
    @qColumn nvarchar(10) = 'BlackWhite',
    @orderColumn nvarchar(20) = 'GameID',
    @orderDirection bit = 1,
    @PageSize int = 25,
    @CurrentPage int = 0)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Offset int;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @Offset = @PageSize * @CurrentPage

    SELECT 
        [GameID], [Event], [Site], [Date], [White], [Black], [Result], [ECO] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[pgnGames]  
    WHERE 
         CASE @qColumn
             WHEN 'BlackWhite' THEN [Black]
             WHEN 'Event' THEN [Event]
             WHEN 'Black' THEN [Black]
             WHEN 'White' THEN [White]
             WHEN 'ECO' THEN  [ECO] 
             WHEN 'Result' THEN [Result] 
          END LIKE  '%'+ @qText +'%' OR
          CASE @qColumn
             WHEN 'BlackWhite' THEN [White]
             WHEN 'Event' THEN [Event]
             WHEN 'Black' THEN [Black]
             WHEN 'White' THEN [White]
             WHEN 'ECO' THEN  [ECO] 
             WHEN 'Result' THEN [Result] 
          END LIKE  '%'+ @qText +'%'
       ORDER BY 
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Black' 
                    AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [Black] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Black' 
                    AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [Black] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Date' 
                    AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [Date] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Date'  
                    AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [Date] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'ECO' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [ECO] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'ECO' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [ECO] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Event' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [Event] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Event' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [Event] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'GameID' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [GameID] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'GameID' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [GameID] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Result' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [Result] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Result' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [Result] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Site' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [Site] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'Site' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [Site] END,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'White' AND @orderDirection = 0 THEN [White] END DESC,
          CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 'White' AND @orderDirection = 1 THEN [White] END
          OFFSET @Offset ROW 
          FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROW ONLY
END
GO
```

here is my Bind Code:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
pgDataContext pl = new pgDataContext();
GameList.DataSource = pl.GetGamesWithPlayer(hdr.qText,hdr.qColumn,GlobalVar.sortColumn,GlobalVar.sortOrder, GlobalVar.pageSize, pgIndex);
GameList.DataBind();
recordCount = pl.pgnGames.Count();
GameList.VirtualItemCount = recordCount;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to store the results in the GridView? Are you calling `DataBind()` afterwards?

Comment: Do you bind Source of your GridView to SqlDataSource?

Comment: Try adding a `.ToList()` after `pl.GetGamesWithPlayer()`. What datatype does that function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the pl.GetGamesWithPlayer result into some var property, and set a breakpoint, are you seeing data in that value after the call? Also, is pgnGames.Count() giving you the correct number? It looks like your code should be:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
pgDataContext pl = new pgDataContext();
var games = pl.GetGamesWithPlayer(hdr.qText,hdr.qColumn,GlobalVar.sortColumn,GlobalVar.sortOrder, GlobalVar.pageSize, pgIndex);
GameList.DataSource = games;
GameList.DataBind();
recordCount = pl.pgnGames.Count();
GameList.VirtualItemCount = recordCount;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

But I'm, not sure how your data access layer works. This assumes that pl.GetGamesWithPlayer returnes the pgnGames object. If that method just fills pl.pgnGames when it's called, then you would just do the following:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
pgDataContext pl = new pgDataContext();
pl.GetGamesWithPlayer(hdr.qText,hdr.qColumn,GlobalVar.sortColumn,GlobalVar.sortOrder, GlobalVar.pageSize, pgIndex);
GameList.DataSource = pl.pgnGames;
GameList.DataBind();
recordCount = pl.pgnGames.Count();
GameList.VirtualItemCount = recordCount;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

If you're sure the right data is going into the data source, then I'd recommend you put in some of the grid events, like DataBinding, RowDataBound, etc and step through to see if you can tell why the data isn't available.

Comment: Thx this method work
pl.GetGamesWithPlayer(hdr.qText,hdr.qColumn,GlobalVar.sortColumn,GlobalVar.sortOrder, GlobalVar.pageSize, pgIndex);
GameList.DataSource = pl.pgnGames;